# Record Video of my running application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to record a video of my application which is running on my iPhone and use it for Replay. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this and could't find any solution.

Your only options are:
1. Run the app in the simulator and use any screen capture tool for mac to record a video
2. Fix the iPhone on a pod/stand and record video of you app with another camera

If the app does not have any feature which is available only on the device i would avoid option no 2, because iPhone's glossy screen shows all kinds of reflections and the user's hand in the video is really annoying..

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your phone is a 4S you can get a dongle from Apple that outputs the video as a HD stream. The dongle lets you plug in a HDMI cable, so you would need some way to capture that output.